# Build Error while converting python file into apk using buildozer

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have made a simple app in python using Kivy and now I want this to be converted into an apk file so that I can use it in my android mobile.
But constantly I am getting following build error while converting it. I am using buildozer for building an apk file.
I have checked for any missing files or directory, but that's not the case. OS : UBUNTU 12.04. The Error is :

```
[aapt] ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/platform-tools/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

BUILD FAILED
~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/ant/build.xml:645: The following error occurred while executing this line:
~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/ant/build.xml:683: null returned: 127

Total time: 1 second
.
.
.
assets/private.mp3: /home/manish/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.pyo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 412, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 336, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python2.7 build.py --name 'My Application' --version 1.0 --package org.test.myapp --private /home/manish/kivy/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape --window debug
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. When you are posting a question can you also post the details of your system OS, programs you are using etc. It will usually help to get an answer quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to install ia32libs. use " sudo apt-get install ia32-libs " command on ubuntu. I got this question's answer on IRC channel of kivy and it worked for me. Initially i have not installed it as it is for 32-bit system. They said that android tools still require us to download and install ia32-libs on 64bit systems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly generic error that could cover a few different things. Could you paste the full log from buildozer (including with the --verbose option, or `log_level = 2` in your buildozer.spec.

You can also do some basic troubleshooting, like check you have the build dependencies installed. I'm not sure which ones could cause this, maybe make sure you have javac (via openjdk probably).

Comment: I have made log_level = 2 in buildozer.spec file. Actually I have followed every step that has been told in video lecture provided by www.kivy.org. If some build dependencies are not present, do buildozer doesn't install them itself?

Comment: buildozer can install some android dependencies itself, but not absolutely everything it needs. The video is a little misleading here. Could you check you have openjdk (and the javac binary) installed?

Comment: Yes, they are installed on my system. When i typed the command <java  -version > in terminal, following output is printed :            java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

Zlib development package is installed?

You can try:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Or some missing packages.

Comment: Yeah, this one is already installed. How can I know which packages are missing, that are essential for this build.