# Buildozer "Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1"

Tags: android, python, fedora, kivy

I try to compile a basic code with buildozer. At first run it installs depencies and fail. Later runs it just fails.

any help needed desperately.

Thanks in advance.

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/mbp/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/ant/build.xml:645: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/mbp/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/ant/build.xml:651: null returned: 127

Total time: 1 second
form/python-for-android/dist/sozluk/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/modules/inspector.pyo
...
.....
...
assets/private.mp3: /home/mbp/build/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/sozluk/private/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
assets/private.mp3: /home/mbp/build/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.pyo
assets/private.mp3: /home/mbp/build/.buildozer/android/app/main.pyo
assets/private.mp3: /home/mbp/build/.buildozer/android/app/sozluk.kv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 412, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 336, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 542, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name DenemeSozluk --version 1.2.0 --package bs.sozluk.sozluk --private /home/mbp/build/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation sensor debug
```

Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
I found following question about very similar problem on ubuntu. It might not be distro specific.
[Build Error while converting python file into apk using buildozer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145721/build-error-while-converting-python-file-into-apk-using-buildozer)

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.12.9-301.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 29 15:56:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Full output:
http://paste.fedoraproject.org/82968/41173791/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generic error, it could mean a lot of things.

One thing to check is that you have buildozer's dependencies installed...in particular, I think the lack of a jdk (and javac) can cause this. Do you have these?

Comment: Ended up being a dependency issue as you said. Something was wrong with cython version.Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced this error and from [github](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/205) found that it happened because google has updated their sdk version to 24.So my quick fix in buildozer was to set following property in buildozer.spec and my app worked fine afterwards.

```
# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 24
```