# Buildozer command failed

Tags: android, python, kivy

so I am trying to deploy a simple program to my Galaxy S5 with Buildozer. I run `buildozer --verbose android debug deploy run` which goes fine until the very last part:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 491, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 354, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name 'School Organized' --version 1.2.0 --    package org.test.schoolorganized --private /home/jolechiw/School-Organized/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape debug
```

The last part of the output can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/TJV2xwMz). I really dont understand what went wrong with "Command Failed" but it might be a path error? I am really not sure.

EDIT:

I dont know if this matters but my source code for the app is [here](http://github.com/pianist1119/school-organized)

Comment: Could you run buildozer with the --verbose option or with log_level=2 in the buildozer.spec? This will display a lot more information. For now, my guess is a dependency error.

Comment: @inclement well well! I changed the wording of my searches and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228089/buildozer-command-ant-debug-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1 thanks for the help with --verbose :) im gonna try making a virtualenv to go through dependencies again

Answer (score 0):

I had, I believe, the same problem recently, and I'm fairly sure the problem was really the **name of my app**.

I don't think you can have a space in the name `'School Organized'`. Try removing that or replacing it with an underscore (or whatever), **wherever it appears** in your `buildozer.spec` file, and build again.

I don't really have a way to check this was definitely the same error as mine, but it was at the least very similar and this tweak definitely fixed it.

Comment: thanks :) ill try it, but recently ive been using the kivy virtual machine to try to compile and im having errors with that too! :(

Answer (score 0):

today I had the same building issue. The problem was in Java itself rather than in buildozer.

It **MUST** be done using **Java 7**:

```
piotr@jnlk ~/Kivy/SomeApp $ which java
/usr/bin/java

piotr@jnlk ~/Kivy/SomeApp $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

piotr@jnlk ~/Kivy/SomeApp $ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
(...)
# Distribution already compiled, pass.
# Build the application #137
# Package the application
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python2 build.py (...) --orientation landscape debug
```

Building with Java8 fails, but when I changed JAVA_HOME variable to the  location of Java7:

```
piotr@jnlk ~/Kivy/SomeApp $ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
piotr@jnlk ~/Kivy/SomeApp $ export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

piotr@jnlk ~/Kivy/SomeApp $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

piotr@jnlk ~/Kivy/SomeApp $ buildozer android debug
piotr@jnlk ~/Kivy/SomeApp $ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
(...)
# Android packages installation done.
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Distribution already compiled, pass.
# Build the application #138
# Package the application
# Android packaging done!
# APK <some-app-name>.apk available in the bin directory
```

Building was completed successfully :)