# Buildozer on kivy-example fails to build apk

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I've installed kivy (on debian jessie / python 2.7), and the examples work fine,

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential ccache git zlib1g-dev python2.7 python2.7-dev 
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 
sudo pip install colorama appdirs sh jinja2 six
sudo pip install --upgrade colorama
sudo apt-get install pkg-config autoconf automake libtool
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install cython  #installs 0.21.1
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-kivy python-kivy-examples  #installs 1.8.0
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/kivi-examples/  #install made it Read-Only Root
sudo pip install --upgrade buildozer  #installs 0.32
sudo easy_install buildozer  #just in case?
sudo pip install python-for-android  #0.4?
java -version #reports 1.8.0_121
```

but when I try to buildoze any of the kivy-examples it has an error.  I've set the log_level = 2 in the .spec file, but I don't see anything in the console output that suggests what could be the problem

```
/usr/share/kivy-examples/demo/touchtracer$ buildozer init
...
/usr/share/kivy-examples/demo/touchtracer$ buildozer -v android debug
/usr/share/kivy-examples/demo/touchtracer$ buildozer -v android_new debug
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at     sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at     sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
# Command failed: /home/guest/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android list sdk -u -e
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
```

Also, at some point while I was trying to build, it was downloading the android sdk every time I ran buildozer, but now that stopped.. or at least it's not not getting to that point anymore.

Is it possible that upgrading to python 3 then installing python3-kivy will solve this?  I noticed my current install did not grab the latest (kivy 1.9.1 / android sdk 21)

[Update #1] I installed newer versions of buildozer (.33dev), cython (25.2), and kivy (1.9.2.dev0)

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git
cd buildozer
sudo python setup.py install
cd ..
sudo pip install Cython==0.25.2  #kivy 1.9.2.dev0 required Cython >= 0.23
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy
cd kivy
sudo python setup.py install
```

and updated the .spec file :

```
requirements = python2,kivy==master
android.sdk = 24
```

but still no luck.   The only other thing I could find to try is to downgrade java8 to java7.   Does buildoze not work with 8?
[Buildozer command failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072798/buildozer-command-failed)

[Update #2] I uninstalled Java8 ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java ) and installed Java 1.7.0_80 but I get the same exact error

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
java -version
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Try `buildozer android_new debug` instead. It will probably at least give a better error.

Comment: Thanks, but the output looks the same...  strange that --verbose is anything but!    I'd like to keep java8 but is it possible that this works only using java7?

Answer (score -1):

BuilDozer is obsolete as of now. Forget it. I am stuck with it as asked here: [Buildozer gives error upon building Pong app of Kivy framework for android publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613329/buildozer-gives-error-upon-building-pong-app-of-kivy-framework-for-android-publi)

Try [Python for Android](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [QPython](https://www.qpython.com/)