# Buildozer gives error upon building Pong app of Kivy framework for android publishing

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to make an apk file using buildozer of the Pong App (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html)

However I am getting the following error on running the buildozer final step.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.38.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1053, in run_command
    targets = [x[0] for x in self.targets()]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 945, in targets
    fromlist=['buildozer'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android_new.py", line 10, in <module>
    from buildozer.targets.android import TargetAndroid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 28, in <module>
    import sh
ImportError: No module named sh
```

Please let me know the solution to proceed to make the apk file

Reference: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like Buidozer is having issues finding the sh package. Take a look at https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-sh-in-python. Dont feel bad, I have had similar experiences with Buildozer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It helped me got ahead but again it stucks at a position while unzipping NDK. It says: bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: I wish you the best of luck. That is also as far as I got when trying a few months ago.

Comment: It seems buildozer project is not updated to use the latest NDK and forcefull tries to download the old NDK even if we place other downloaded NDK in its directory. Buildozer seems to be nothing but a Waste of Time,